# what version of mysql are datasources using?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a calculated table that uses a join statement SQL query as its data source. good. Works fine.

But then I'm trying to add in the use of :Parameters and my attempts to create a default if it equals null are not working.

I tried this (In the onLoad client script):

```
if (app.datasources.Relations.query.parameters.x== null){
  console.log("No xfound,using >");
  app.datasources.Relations.query.parameters.x= ">";}
```

It works, but not on the initial load (it appears to apply AFTER the first load).

So I decided to try and bake it into the sql statement that makes the table like this, but all three of these iterations failed with "check your version of mysql" errors.

```
AND b.CSI_Code REGEXP select if(:x= null, "<",:x)

AND b.CSI_Code REGEXP select if(:x== null, "<",:x)

AND b.CSI_Code REGEXP select if(:x=== null, "<",:x)
```

I've got a workaround going where I set my parameters to the APP onload rather than the datasource onload,but ultimately I think it would be cleaner if I could get the SQL if nul set to default (">") part working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the Google Cloud Platform where your database is hosted, it lists the database version in the instance information (see picture). [Per the FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#version), the options are currently MySQL 5.5, 5.6, or 5.7. If you click into the instance, and go to the Databases tab, each app has its own database with a name like "Wc7cVzeGEvbPjxj4". To confirm which database your app uses, the name should be listed in your Google App Maker app under (Your app in the developer GUI) > Settings Cog Icon > Database > Database Key.

[image: Google Cloud Platform SQL Instances]